# Plot solutions of ODEs with varying initial conditions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a system of 2 differential equations with 2 variables. I then want to plot x(t) vs t for various initial conditions, and then do the same for y(t) vs t for various initial conditions. I'm struggling with doing this though, for some reason the  MATLAB syntax is not clicking with me at all.

Here is the system of differential equations that I am trying to solve.

```
function dpdt = lODE(t,p)

dpdt = [-3*p(1) + 2*p(2);
        -p(1) + (-1 + -2*p(2))];
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here's some more context, and my actual code.

```
syms y(t) z(t);
eqns = [diff(y,t)==-3*y+2*z, diff(z,t)==y-2*z];
[ySol(t),zSol(t)] = dsolve(eqns);
```

This outputs the solution as a symfunc, which means I can't use it in PLOT. Again, my goal is to plot one of the solutions versus time.

Comment: Where is `t` in your system?

Comment: The system is autonomous, so t (the time variable) does not impact the rate of change. However t of course would be used in the solution.

Comment: What is the problem? Is it giving you an error?
Also, why are you using `.*` ?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to use matlab to make the particular plot that I need. Also the star was an error in copying, I fixed it in the original post. I'll add an edit that shows the general idea of what I want to do.